# How to use python selenium to continue when new message special shows up on the site?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Im making a messenger project to auto respond and my question is is it possible to make bot wait 20 seconds for new message but if not receives it it closes?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait 20 seconds and  make a try/except to click on the message or just close the tab

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, I am not sure what exactly you mean but you could just run a timer for example:

```
import time

i =1
while i == 1:
     // Run a check for a message e.g store the value in a variable (in our case message)
     message = // Selenium get element
     if message != "":
           // send a message
     else:
           // make our program wait to re-run this code agian checking to see if a message has been sent
           time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: that didnt work, the bot starts spamming the text when someone isnt replied before the bot startes to work. I need something that waits for the reply